# How to update a database record and still keep the old values in sql

Tags: sql

I have a sql table architecture as

```
 SQL> desc etpro_update;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(4000)
 IS_ACTIVE                                          NUMBER
 CREATED_DATE                                       DATE
```

where IS_ACTIVE column has been set to default value of 1.So how can we store same data(record) into a table with column IS_ACTIVE having values 0 & 1.
So final output should looks like as below

```
123         test      1      2017_12_03
123         test      0      2017_12_03
```

Comment: I generally go with `Select * into NewTable from etpro_update where is_active in (0,1)`

Comment: i have made correction in question and the requirement is like how can we store the same record in same table with different value of IS_ACTIVE column.where IS_ACTIVE is set to 1 by default.

Comment: SQL> and capitals and `desc` make me think this is Oracle. Please tag the database type if it is Oracle. To add a record you use `INSERT`. To determine whether it's 0 or 1 you need to know if the record exists. To know if the record exists you need to match on a unique key. So what is the unique key here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table with data having `IS_ACTIVE` as `0` or `1`, then try:

```
create table some_table as
select * from etpro_update
where is_active in (0, 1);
```

If it's already existing, do `INSERT` using the `SELECT`:

```
insert into some_table (
    id,
    name,
    is_active,
    created_date
    )
select id,
    name,
    is_active,
    created_date
from etpro_update
where is_active in (0, 1);
```